# context menu parent?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

Hi I added a context menu on label (c#, winforms). my context menu having 3 child items and i want to display label text when i click on any one of context menu items.

thanks in advance

Comment: where do want the text and where from? From the label or on the label?

Comment: Have you considered using a combo box? This might be more intuitive for your users to understand

Comment: i want to display the label text (label is nothing but paret for context menu)

Comment: As fredrik says use SourceControl. Can you use `((Label)SourceControl).Text`

Answer (score 28):

The [`ContextMenuStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx) control has a [`SourceControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol.aspx) property, that will have a reference to the control that opened it. You can use that to extract the text from the control:

```
private void MenuStripItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripItem item = (sender as ToolStripItem);
    if (item != null)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip owner = item.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
        if (owner != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(owner.SourceControl.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

If you instead of a `ContextMenuStrip` use a `ContextMenu`, the code should look like this:

```
private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = (sender as MenuItem);
    if (item != null)
    {
        ContextMenu owner = item.Parent as ContextMenu;
        if (owner != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(owner.SourceControl.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to display the label text (label is nothing but paret for context menu)

Comment: hey here we are getting MenuItem not ToolStripItem

Answer (score 5):

Its the best in one line:

```
Control control = ((ContextMenuStrip)((ToolStripItem)sender).Owner).SourceControl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Context Menu Parent Control Name
MessageBox.Show(contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl.Name.ToString());