# How do i access the originating control for a ContextMenuStrip in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenustrip

I have attached a ContextMenuStrip to a TabControl and set up a handler for OnMouseDown that does the following:

```
  if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right) {
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; ++i) {
    var point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

    if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(point)) {
      tabPageContextMenu.Show(tabControl1, point);
    }
  }
```

This properly shows the ContextMenuStrip however, inside the Click event for the MenuItem contained by the ContextMenuStrip I cannot seem to access the underlying TabControl or TabPage that actually spawned the ContextMenuStrip.

The questions then becomes this:  How can I best access the originating control?  Obviously in the MouseDown handler I could assign the control to a private class variable but I assumed there was a standard way via some property that I am currently overlooking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this answer may be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334155/context-menu-parent/1334186#1334186

Comment: Awesome!  I promise I DID search before posting but I obviously missed that one.  SourceControl is exactly what I was looking for but just wasn't finding it.  Thanks again for helping a .Net noob. :)

Comment: You might also find it easier to use the Opening event of the ContextMenuStrip rather than working around the MouseDown event.

Comment: I don't think I can;  I want the ContextMenuStrip to open when I right click on one of the tab headers as right clicks on the tab body perform a very different function.

Due to this I'm currentl hecking the TabControl's list of TabRects to confirm that the mouse is indeed on a header before calling Show().

Everything seems to be working now though. I just assign the TabPage that matches the index of the clicked TabRect as SourceControl and handle everything else in the MenuStripItem clicked event.

Again, thanks to everyone for all the input!