# How can I connect to parent item to sub menu item

Tags: c#, menu

[context menu parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334155/context-menu-parent)

I saw that question and checked it runs well.
And I edited some and test again

- Menu 1

  - Menu 2
- Menu 3

When I make menu like that and tested, there is some problem on menu 2.

on Menu3

```
ToolStripMenuItem item = (sender as ToolStripMenuItem); //works well
ContextMenuStrip owner = item.source; //works well
string str = owner.SourceControl.Text; //works well
```

on Menu2

```
ToolStripMenuItem item = (sender as ToolStripMenuItem); //works well
ContextMenuStrip owner = item.OwnerItem.source; //works well
string str = owner.SourceControl.Text; //error - owner.SourceControl is null
```

I tested this and get different result

> chart1.ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl

On Menu3, shows well.
On Menu2, shows null.

How can I connect to parent item to sub menu item?

Comment: I seem to recall this is a well-known bug.  To get around it, declare a private variable in your class, _chosenContextMenu.  Then, you keep updating its value so that, at all times, you know the parent menu.

Comment: Like yours, I did it by alternative way. Add event to menu`s parent when mouse is in control. Event saves control that has occured event. After that, I can use my functions well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the ToolStripMenuItem 's tag is not used, you could store its parent ToolStripMenuItem into its tag.