# C# GUI "Context Menue Strip" Parent

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have the flowing problem I have multiple buttons that call same  ContextMenuStrip  and in turn some ToolStripMenuItem of Context Menue .
I need to get the owner or the Parent (The Button) which called the ToolStripMenuItem .

I tried

```
private void findToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
            ContextMenuStrip mContextMenuStrip = (ContextMenuStrip)menuItem.GetCurrentParent();
            String type = mContextMenuStrip.Parent.Name.ToString();

        }
```

My question is not similar to existing question because provided answer not working. I need Parent of Parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [context menu parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334155/context-menu-parent)

Answer (score 0):

```
ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    ContextMenuStrip mContextMenuStrip = (ContextMenuStrip)menuItem.GetCurrentParent();
    if (mContextMenuStrip.SourceControl.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown"))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown SelectedControl = (System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown)mContextMenuStrip.SourceControl;
    }
```